# File size limit of 100.00 in previous commit

Tags: git, github

I am having "File size limit of 100.00" in previous commit due to one file. I do not want to upload this zip file but now is commited in local and it is 2 commits before the one I am now.

Everytime that I am trying to push the new commits it shown me the error again, because it is trying to push the previous ones as well.

The stack it is the following:

### Commits

```
Commit1 (Actual)
Commit2
f0ce53a
Commit3
  ...
```

The zip file is in f0ce53a, also in this commit there are some changes that I want to push them.

**There is any way to push the commit f0ce53a without the zip file?**

Thank you so much,
if you need any further information let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix the problem is an interactive rebase (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode) for documentation):

```
git rebase -i Commit3
```

You'll get an editable text file that looks like this:

```
pick f0ce53a Add a big pesky zip file and some other stuff
pick Commit2 Misc. changes
pick Commit1 Misc. changes
```

There will be some helpful commented lines at the bottom of the file listing the various possible commands. The ones we care about are `pick`, which means the commit should be used as is, and `edit`, which will stop the rebase at the given commit to allow us to amend it.

`f0ce53a` is the commit where the zip file was added so we'll change `pick` to `edit` on that line, leaving us with:

```
edit f0ce53a Add a big pesky zip file and some other stuff
pick Commit2 Misc. changes
pick Commit1 Misc. changes
```

Save the file and quit (vim: `:x`), and you'll be on the problem commit. Remove the zip file and amend the commit, then continue the rebase:

```
git rm foo.zip
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

You've rewritten history as though the zip file was never committed.

Comment: Tons of thank you for the answer seems everything is working fine, but I am in last step and I am receiving that:

foo.zip: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add

Comment: @Eironeia just delete (or move) the zip in your file system

Comment: Solved, tons of thanks for such a good answer. Everything already pushed!